# Image icons is not fixed with variable screen size

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm making a section in which there is a `<div>` containing big-image, and three  image icons. I have fixed them for large and extra large image, but as soon as the screen size changes it's position, the big-image changes it's size and the icons moves away from the place. I want to make them fix.

This is the website : [SERVICES](https://www.bjios.sg/services-facilities/), which does not works like that, but the idea is similar. It has circular dots which becomes active, and irrespective of the screen size you'll find the circular dots fixed on the same position. I have tried my level best but couldn't get the desired result. **This is the dummy code I have written via code snippet so as to give you a clearer idea what my code is actually.**

```css
a img.img-logo {width: 55px; height: 55px; visibility: visible}
  a.intro-logo-1 {top: 33.6%;left: 57.6%; position:absolute; cursor: pointer}
  a.intro-logo-2 {top: 71.8%; left: 32.5%; position:absolute; cursor: pointer}
  a.intro-logo-3 {top: 84.2%; left: 25%; position:absolute; cursor: pointer}
```

```html
<div class='row' style='height: 100%'>
      <div class="col-5 box-one slideshow-wrapper">
        BOX CONTENT
      </div>
      <div class='logo-grp col-7' style='position: relative'>
        <img src='http://www.stickpng.com/assets/images/580b57fcd9996e24bc43c53e.png' alt='' style='width: 550px; height: 690px'>
        <a class='intro-logo-1'><img class='img-logo' src='http://www.stickpng.com/assets/images/580b57fcd9996e24bc43c53e.png'></a>
        <a class='intro-logo-2'><img class='img-logo' src='http://www.stickpng.com/assets/images/580b57fcd9996e24bc43c53e.png'></a>
        <a class='intro-logo-3'><img class='img-logo' src='http://www.stickpng.com/assets/images/580b57fcd9996e24bc43c53e.png'></a>
      </div>
    </div>
```

The result is like this, for the wide screen it is :

[image: PERFECT IMAGE ON WIDE SCREEN]

The result when the screen size reduced :

[image: MISPLACED ICONS]

Please help, I have tried my level best. Need to get the result. Thanks folks in advance.

Comment: Code snippet is not working, image doesn't show up.

Comment: Hey @SagarSolanki, the image I'm using is different from the icons I have used here. Just a dummy code, so that to give you a good idea, what my code looks like

Comment: have you referred this? [aspect ratio boxes](https://css-tricks.com/aspect-ratio-boxes/)

Comment: You need to set your image and container width & dimensions to be same. i.e. .logo-grp & .logo-grp img should be of same height and width.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't limit the size of the logo group div to the size of the image, so the little images seem to move with respect to the bigger div box. Simply add:

```
.logo-grp {width: 550px; }
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/jcxq64rz/3

Please note: This seems to be a column in a bootstrap grid, so don't change the column, like I did, but add a div around the image.

Comment: Thanks KIKO, you idea worked out. I just had to make the `width` to `max-width`, and it worked. However, there is a little bit of wobble that can be seen when the screen size changes, that is fine. The image icons doesn't change the position too much. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give an absolute position to your icon image but the main image needs to be aligned with the icons.

Refer: [RatioBuddy](https://ratiobuddy.com/)